# Is it possible to nested graph's fragment as the start destination?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-jetpack, android-jetpack-navigation

I'm using navigation component and I want to know whether is it possible to nested graph's fragment as the start destination?

Comment: You can certainly use a nested graph as the start destination of your graph. What made you think it isn't possible?

Comment: It should be as simple as setting the nested graph's ID as the start destination, and then it will initialize itself to the start destination of the nested graph